# JS `import` is undefined, potentially circular import issue?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, babeljs

**Preface**

I'm using `create-react-app` to generate an application.

**Problem**

`TodoList === undefined`

**Code**

*components/index.js*

```
export { default as App } from './App/App.js';
export { default as TodoList } from './TodoList/TodoList.js';
```

*containers/index.js*

```
export { default as VisibleTodoList } from './VisibleTodoList.js';
```

*components/App/App.js*

```
import { VisibleTodoList } from '../../containers/index.js';
```

*containers/VisibleTodoList.js*

```
import { TodoList } from '../components/index.js';
```

*components/TodoList/TodoList.js*

```
export default function TodoList({ todos, onTodoClick }) { ... }
```

---

TodoList is now `undefined`. I believe it may have something to do with the fact that I have some sort of circular issue.

The thing is, if inside *containers/VisibleTodoList.js* I import using the following method, everything works fine.

```
import TodoList from '../components/TodoList/TodoList.js';
```

What is so special that breaks the import, if I try to import using a 'middleman' (the components/index.js file).

**Full code**

I have created a CodeSandbox that contains my full code, as it stands in my application. The application is pretty simplistic, but more complicated than I have outlined here.

https://codesandbox.io/s/m54nql1ky9

Comment: Simple example seems to work fine https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-v5hc2b
Anything else you can tell us about your app structure? If you import the default `App` in `components/index.js`, does it have the proper value?

Comment: you can ignore `.js` when importing.

Comment: @AndreiNemes Importing `App` from components works as expected.

Comment: @Lasitha I know, I was just being consistent and making sure everyone understood I was doing JS, not TS or anything else.

Comment: Your codesandbox sample has other bugs. You don't have a default export in `VisibleTodoList.js`, for one. It looks like this is the actual reason for the error you are getting. The TodoList import is not broken. https://codesandbox.io/s/74mlwnwyy1

Comment: @HåkenLid that's not the issue, I'd commented that out to try and isolate the issue. I've uncommented the export, and it's still the same issue.

Comment: The import works fine here: https://codesandbox.io/s/74mlwnwyy1

Comment: So it does, I saw that you changed the order of the export inside components/index.js, but I'm just getting different errors. What else did you change (other than hooking the store up)?

Comment: @HåkenLid so I figured it all out and got it all working correctly. Interesting that the export ordering matters in this instance. How very peculiar. Thanks buddy.

Comment: I also changed the `store.js` to change the names for the store slices, so they work with the rest of the code. You're right, the order of exports does seem to be what causes this. I didn't really expect that, and I'm not sure if that is something that is defined in the ES spec anywhere, or maybe som babel-specific edge case (bug).

Comment: @AlexMcCabe `export from` order is also import order. And yes, import order matters a lot if you have circular dependencies.

Comment: @Bergi: Do you know of a good reference document about circular imports. In python, circular imports will raise an exception. But in JavaScript it will not throw an error, but instead some imports might silently resolve to `undefined`.

Comment: I'm adding the import order solution as an answer. I think this might be useful for others who come across this in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is caused by the order of *exports* in your `components/index.js` file.

```
export { default as App } from './App/App.js';
export { default as TodoList } from './TodoList/TodoList.js';
```

Since `App.js` imports `VisibleTodoList` which needs to import `TodoList` and pass it to the redux `connect` function before it can export itself, you end up with a conflict.

I'm not sure if this is a implementation quirk of babel, or if this is a logical result from how the ES import spec is defined.

In any case, changing the order of exports fixes the bug.

```
export { default as TodoList } from './TodoList/TodoList.js';
export { default as App } from './App/App.js';
```

As a rule of thumb, if you can't refactor your files to avoid the import loop, you should put the outer layer component last in the list, since it might rely on imports higher up in the list.

Full working codesandbox here: https://codesandbox.io/s/74mlwnwyy1

Comment: It took us a while to get to this point, but given some time to think about it, it's pretty logical. Accepted as answer. An alternative answer is to not import `./components/App/App` into `./components/index` at all, and just use it in the one place.